# How to make an android mobile only running an application from startup?

Tags: android, mobile

Well, today in my workplace i have been given a task. Boss handed me an android mobile, which only runs a application and nothing else. Whenever the mobile starts, it starts the application and users cant nvaigate anywhere from that application. which means the mobile is only dedicated for that application. An ex-employee did this thing.
I need to bring it to normal condition. Then do the same for another application, which is only my application will run in the mobile, as its doing for another app.

How to solve it? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It probably uses [services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Try to `force-factory-reset` your device and see `Services` when developing your app. Also what is the model of your device?

Answer (score 0):

If you **do not care** about the data stored on that mobile then you should perform the factory reset. This will bring your mobile to the fresh state with only OEM apps installed.

To do it you need to enter the recovery mode. If your device has USB debugging mode enabled then simply connect it to the computer and type `adb reboot recovery`. If debugging is not enabled then you have to force the recovery mode then you should do a research on the internet how to put your device in recovery mode. For example for Samsung devices you have to turn off the device and then hold Home+VolumeUp+Power buttons.

Once you enter the recovery mode you will see few options. One of them is "wipe data/factory mode" (see example [here](http://www.howdonkey.com/pics/46/enter-recovery-mode-on-android-smartphones.jpg)). Use volume buttons to navigate through options and power button to accept the option (note that touchscreen is not operable in this mode). Remember that this will erase all your data and you will not be able to restore it. No turning back beyond this point.

After the reset you will have no custom apps installed so you can install whatever you want.

**If you cannot do the factory reset because you do not want to lose your data** then there is other, more difficult option, that requires some Android programming. You can simply write an application that would:

1. run at startup
2. get information about installed packages
3. find the application that has been blocking the device
4. send an intent that would ask the user if he wants to uninstall the app:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+"some.package.to.remove");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```